# Does Riak have any synchronization features to help synch. mobile and web apps?

Tags: riak

Wondering if Riak has anything that would help one synchronize data between a mobile and web application?

i.e. when a user ads a record or updates a record on their phone/web, it would be easy for the application developer to detect the data is out of sych. and cause a refresh of the data displayed.

I have heard couchdb has something, but I'm still investigating my options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Riak has [commit hooks](http://wiki.basho.com/Commit-Hooks.html), where you can test if a value is being changed.

As for CouchDB, I believe you're talking about the [Changes API](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/notifications.html).

Answer (score 1):

Trifork is a partner of Basho, the makers of Riak, and we have made something we call the Riak Sync protocol.

Riak Sync is basicly a bucket synchronization protocol between a Riak cluster somewhere on the internet and a mobile device - or multiple mobile devices. It is based on Merkle trees, and parallel connections, and is quite effecient.

You can see an overview of Riak Sync in this presentation:

http://gotocon.com/dl/goto-aarhus-2011/slides/KrestenKrabThorup_BringingRiakToTheMobilePlatform.pdf

I believe we also have implementations of Riak Sync for the Riak server - obviously - as well as different mobile devices.

Don't hessitate to contact me, if you are interested in using Riak Sync. I can dig some more info up.

Comment: what is license of RiakSync and RiakMobile? Can RiakSync can be used on open source edition of Riak?

Answer (score 0):

**"Riak Mobile" and now the new alternative.** http://www.linkedin.com/groups/Free-GeekNight-in-Malm%C3%B6-about-2583523.S.90093295 says "GOTO speaker Kresten Krab Thorup will present Riak Mobile, a component that can be embedded into your iOS or Android application to make it a full Riak replication-aware peer, and walk through how Riak Mobile works. .. 8. februar, 2012" however Google Search of "Riak+Mobile" does not seem to find the actual software (though I kinda recall reading about it perhaps 6mo ago) but now on the official site I can only find articles as http://basho.com/popular-use-cases-for-mobile-platforms-on-riak/ with just overview details and not mentioning any thing of an embedded software and instead using the transformed phrase "Mobile on Riak" so my educated guess is that the makers of Riak found storing a peer Riak on the mobile device problematic but then did something to cause me to loose notable respect for them: instead of documenting and explaining that problem on their product page and perhaps so marking the product as discontinued if that was truly necessary, **it seemed they've erased all mention of their product "Riak Mobile" from their site**. If I knew the URL, I would dig up the archive.org of "Riak Mobile" to show this.

Comment: http://vimeo.com/26771021 is a video of seemingly this particular showing https://secure.trifork.com/cph-2012/freeevent/index.jsp?eventOID=3854#! of this presentation which includes explaining "Riak Mobile" and "Riak Sync",s algorithm before "a product ready".